# Call procedure in select column MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, jpa, stored-procedures

I have the table Orders and the table Components. It is a many to many relationship and in the relationship table I have a column called "quantity". I have a procedure that calculates the load of a component in all sectors. I add the procedure and the result:

The "identifier" of the component is sent to this procedure as identifierie. It is not the "id" field but I use it in the same way. It can also be seen that a component is recursively related to itself. This is working correctly.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE calculateRecursiveComponentLoad(IN identifierie VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    WITH RECURSIVE components_recursive_components AS (SELECT id, identifier, 1 AS quantity
                                             FROM components
                                             WHERE identifier = identifierie
                                             UNION ALL
                                             SELECT c.id, c.id, c.identifier, cr.quantity
                                             FROM components c
                                                      INNER JOIN component_recursive_component cr ON cr.component_id = c.id
                                                      INNER JOIN components_recursive cr2 ON cr2.id = cr.parent_id)
    SELECT s.description, COALESCE(SUM(o.operation_time * cr.quantity), 0) AS total_time
    FROM sections s
             LEFT JOIN operations o ON o.sections_id = s.id
             LEFT JOIN processes p ON p.operations_id = o.id
             LEFT JOIN components_recursive cr ON cr.id = p.components_id
    GROUP BY s.description;
END
```

And this is the result for if I call calculateRecursiveComponentLoad('1');

[result of call calculateRecursiveComponentLoad('1');](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIcNm.png)

So, I want to calculate the load of an order and have it return the load of the order for each sector.

I have tried this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CalculateOrderLoad(IN orderNum INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE total_load DECIMAL(10, 2);

    SELECT SUM(load * quantity) INTO load_total
    FROM (
        SELECT c.id, c.identifier, pc.quantity, calculateRecursiveComponentLoad(c.identifier) AS load
        FROM orders p
        JOIN order_component pc ON p.id = pc.order_id
        JOIN components c ON pc.component_id = c.id
        WHERE p.order_num = orderNum
    ) AS components;

    SELECT total_load;
END;
```

But it looks it is not working cause it says calculateRecursiveComponentLoad() is not existing.I also think I should change the select of this procedure because I want to visualize the load of the sectors so maybe use load.descripcion(view image) in the select.

Comment: There is no such thing as an inline call to a procedure , you can only invoke a FUNCTION inline

Comment: Stored procedure cannot be used as a datasource in a query. You may either convert it to stored function (if it must return scalar value), or save your SELECT into temptable, call SP then use the data from this temptable in the next queries.

Comment: @Akina I want calculateRecursiveComponentLoad to be called for all lines of order_component. For each component. Could you write the code of how it would be done please? I have tried to create a function but it does not work. I have also seen a FUNCTION can't return TABLE...

Comment: @P.Salmon I have seen a Function can't return a table

Comment: *how it would be done* Add into your SP `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` with the structure which can receive the output of your `SELECT` then convert your `SELECT` to `INSERT .. SELECT`. After SP call you will have temptable which contains recalculated data. Then you can use this temptable in your query.